# X-neighbors of a pixel JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, pixel

I'm working on image processing using JavaScript and I would like to you know if there was any generic formula to determine the x-neighbors of a pixel.

I know that for a 3*3 square there is 8 neighbors that can be determine using a specific x and y pixel.

(x-1,y-1) , (x-1,y) , (x-1,y+1),

(x,y-1) , (x,y) , (x,y+1),

(x+1,y-1) , (x+1,y) , (x+1,y+1).

The problem is that I'm working with 5*5 squares,7*7 squares and 9*9 squares and I was wondering if there was any way to have all the x-neighbors of a pixel from those three squares without having to write the location manually in my program.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use 2 for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var size = 5;
var d = Math.floor(size / 2);

for (var dx = -d; dx <= d; dx++) {
    for (var dy = -d; dy <= d; dy++) {
        if (dx || dy) {
             // Do something with (x + dx, y + dy)
        }
    }
}
```

If you're doing this is a lot (i.e. for every pixel in an image), it might be worth first creating a flat array of value first:

```
var size = 5;
var d = Math.floor(size / 2);
var dPixels = [];

for (var dx = -d; dx <= d; dx++) {
    for (var dy = -d; dy <= d; dy++) {
        if (dx || dy) {
             dPixels.push(dx, dy);
        }
    }
}

// Then for each pixel (x, y)
for (var i = 0; i < dPixels.length; i += 2){
     // Do something with x + dPixels[i], y + dPixels[i + 1]
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this seems obvious now that I saw it